# How to select the first 30 rows from a set?

Tags: sql

I am trying to pick out a column name MSISDN rom the No_Occupation table and then select the top 300 rows from the result. this is the script I used:

```
WITH PagingCte AS (
SELECT [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],[User Category],
Row_Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name])
From AllBalance_20230119)

SELECT [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],Row_Num
FROM PagingCte
WHERE [Account ID] IN (SELECT [MSISDN] FROM No_Occupation)
AND Row_Num BETWEEN 1 AND 300;
AND [User Category] = 'Subscriber';
```

But after I execute the script, I got to result shown.
What am I missing?

I tried the code below

```
WITH PagingCte AS (
SELECT [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],[User Category],
Row_Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name])
From AllBalance_20230119)

SELECT [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],Row_Num
FROM PagingCte
WHERE [Account ID] IN (SELECT [MSISDN] FROM No_Occupation)
AND Row_Num BETWEEN 1 AND 300;
AND [User Category] = 'Subscriber';
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: this looks like SQL Server, why not just use top with an order by?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. SQL Server, in particular, offers a [TOP (300)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the CTE?

You could just inner join to no occupation to eliminate non-matches and use top and order by...

```
SELECT TOP 300 [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],[User Category]
FROM AllBalance_20230119
INNER JOIN No_Occupation 
 on AllBalance_20230119.[Account ID] = No_Occupation.[MSISDN]
WHERE [User Category = 'Subscriber'
ORDER BY [User Name]
```

or use exists since you're not returning data from no_occupation, you just need to know the account ID exists in the set..

```
SELECT TOP 300 [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],[User Category]
FROM AllBalance_20230119
WHERE [User Category = 'Subscriber'
  and exists (SELECT 1 FROM No_Occupation 
              WHERE AllBalance_20230119.[Account ID] = No_Occupation.[MSISDN])
ORDER BY [User Name]
```

Order of operations will matter here so

- FROM
- where
- order by
- Select
- top

The order by occurs before the top ensuring you get those top 300 based on user name.

Answer (score 0):

With your query, there is no guarantee that there would be a row with [User Category] = 'Subscriber' in the first 1-300 rows. Why don't you simply use TOP (SQL server it seems to be - else LIMIT):

```
SELECT top(300) [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],Row_Number() over (Order by  [User Name]) Row_Num
FROM AllBalance_20230119
WHERE [Account ID] IN (SELECT [MSISDN] FROM No_Occupation)
AND [User Category] = 'Subscriber'
order by [User Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer changes due the DBMS that you are using.
Anyway, you can use LIMIT keyword in order to select first n rows from a query result.
LIMIT works with a lot of DBMS as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc..

You can implement LIMIT in this way:

```
SELECT [Account ID],[User Name],[Last Name],[User Category],
Row_Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [User Name])
From AllBalance_20230119
ORDER BY Row_Num
LIMIT 300
```